# Get all deleted record

Tags: subsonic

I'm looking for a way to get all records where `deleted` is set to `true` on a particular table. How might I accomplish this?

Note: Using auto-generated class by SubSonic. Not T-SQL.

Comment: Is this SQL? Is there a column named "deleted" in your table? It would help if you were a little more specific.

Comment: It appears that he is using a framework called SubSonic.  That probably plays a role in his question, but I am equally confused.

Comment: Yes, I using SubSonic. ^__^

By default, SubSonic is load un-deleted recoder. But I want deleted record.

Help me!

Comment: The very fact that the subsonic webpage has a title that is "All your database belongs to us" tells me that this is a non-problem. The actual problem is that you're using SubSonic. This is compounded by the fact that they use "terms" like "batman utility belt" and similar. "Hey guys, we're targetting KIDS now!!!11"

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  Not being familiar with the platform is no reason to downvote if that's why the question is "unclear" to you.  It clearly states which platform is being used and what he's trying to accomplish.  It's like downvoting a question about monads in Haskell because you've never heard of them before - it doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: I agree, there's no reason for downvoting this question.

Comment: @Tadmas: I thought that too, and then I looked at the revisions. It's a lot better now. @Lasse: Embrace the inner child. You know you want to.

Comment: I do it! Thanks everyone!

Have a good week!

Comment: @ranomore: I saw the revisions too, but I first saw the question after the revision that added the "using SubSonic" note (making it clear), and the question was at 0.  It got two more downvotes after that.  Could have been a page refresh race condition, but it doesn't take THAT long to read and downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The auto-generated SubSonic classes don't support querying logical deletes. But you can do this (version 2.1/2.2 syntax):

```
public partial class TableClassCollection
{

    public TableClassCollection LoadAll(bool suppressLogicalDeletes)
    {

          SubSonic.SqlQuery q = new SubSonic.Select(TableClass.Schema)
              .From(TableClass.Schema);

          if (suppressLogicalDeletes)
          {
              q.Where(TableClass.DeletedColumn).IsEqualTo(false);
          }

          return q.ExecuteAsCollection<TableClassCollection>();
      }

}
```

More examples at [subsonicproject.com](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/)

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of SubSonic before, but a quick Google search turned up:  [Select Queries in SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/).

So, using that page as a guide, it sounds like you'd be able to write your query as:

```
FooCollection deletedFoos = // use the generated collection class
    DB.Select().From("FooTable") // table name goes here
        .Where("deleted").IsEqualTo(true) // might need 1, depends on database?
        .ExecuteAsCollection<FooCollection>(); // should match the type above
```

Comment: That's pretty good for never having heard of SubSonic before.

Answer (score -1):

not a lot of detail in your question, but assuming there's a column named "deleted," it would look something like this:

```
select * from tableName where deleted = true
```